# Error when plotting natural cubic spline with knots

Tags: r, spline

```
library(splines)
set.seed(3)
x <- rnorm(100)
plot(x)
lines(ns(x))
```

This works just fine, but if I try to add specific knots, i.e.

```
lines(ns(x, knots = c(1, 2, 3, 50)))
```

Running the above code gives me the following error:

```
Error in qr.default(t(const)) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

Edit:

As per Peter's suggestion, a knot at 50 is way to big, so I modify the code to:

```
> lines(ns(x, knots = sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)[1:10]))
Error in qr.default(t(const)) : 
      NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

Now I want to place 10 knots at the 10 highest values of `x`. But I'm still getting an error? Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

50 is way too big. x is a normal with mean 0 and sd 1.  So, e.g

```
lines(ns(x, knots = c(1, 1.5)))
```

works fine. (One more example of an unhelpful R error message).

Comment: Thank you. I ran into the same error when I tried to use `lines(ns(x, knots = sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)[1:10]))` i.e. placing knots at the 10 highest values. Why is this?